# Kendo UI doesnt call Action Result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use Kendo UI in ASp.NET 5 . I have a Action Method To show Data . its :
I do not add any javascript code , Do Need?

```
 public virtual ActionResult ReadData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        request.Page = 1;
        IEnumerable<ShowProvinceVM> ddd = _provinceService.GetAll().Select(x => new ShowProvinceVM { Id = province.ProvinceId, Name = province.ProvinceName, NameEn = province.ProvinceNameEn, Code = province.ProvinceCode }).ToList();
        DataSourceResult result = ddd.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        result.Total = 20;
        return Json(result, "text/x-json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And My Helper for show grid data is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CMS.ViewModel.Province.ShowProvinceVM>
()
.Name("grid2")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("ReadData", "Province"))
)
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
columns.Bound(c => c.Name);

})

.Pageable()
.Sortable()

)
```

But when I run Project , Its empty and dont call Action Methods.
Whats Problem ?
When I pass Data from Action Index to View and edit Grid like this , It show Data :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model) //Bind the grid to ViewBag.Products
  .Name("grid")

  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      // Create a column bound to the ProductID property
      columns.Bound(product => product.Id);
      // Create a column bound to the ProductName property

      columns.Bound(product => product.Name);
  })
  .Pageable() // Enable paging

                      .Pageable()
                      .Sortable()
```

My routing :

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "lang",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, namespaces: new string[] { "CMS.mvcApp.Controllers" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "langvalueparam",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{value}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", value = UrlParameter.Optional }, namespaces: new string[] { "CMS.mvcApp.Controllers" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, namespaces: new string[] { "CMS.mvcApp.Controllers" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
   "AdminDefault",
   "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   new { area = "Admin", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, namespaces: new string[] { "CMS.mvcApp.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });
        routes.MapRoute(
  "AdminPage",
  "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{page}",
  new { area = "Admin", controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional }, namespaces: new string[] { "CMS.mvcApp.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });
```

Comment: Have you tried calling "ToDataSourceResult()" on the result?   Try this in your controller return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: My action never call . I update Post

Comment: when click grid title columns I getting this error : `The resource cannot be found.` window refresh and redirect to this url `http://localhost:20852/Admin/Province/ReadData?grid2-sort=Name-asc`

Comment: You say you are not hitting a breakpoint in your controller and the message returned is "The resource cannot be found", this sounds very much like a routing issue. Do you have fancy routing, can you post your routing configuration?

Comment: Just curious are you meaning to call http://localhost:20852/Province/ReadData?grid2-sort=Name-asc instead.

Comment: @lrb Please see My routing , I updated

Comment: And your Province controller is in the admin area?

Comment: And your Grid is in a view off of the Admin Area folder, correct?

Comment: @lrb whats problem ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have all of your configuration in order. At this point, it could be a number of things such as Incorrect Page Handler configuration, forms authentication redirect. I would just post as much as you can about the error. Can you post the network request and response headers and body from an F12 debug tools network trace for the call.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that kendo send it's read request as POST!
You need to define the request type if you want to use GET (which it seems as you use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

```
.Read(read => read.Action("ReadData", "Province").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
```